# How to exec jar file from php script in docker

Tags: java, php, docker

I have `php`, `mysql`, `nginx` in docker.
Now I have to run jar file with parameters from php script.

I've added java to my `docker-compose.yml` (part of docker-compose is below)

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  php:
    build: ./configs/php
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./app/basic:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
      - java

  java:
    image: openjdk:7
```

And I'm trying to execute the following part of code from php script:

```
$command = "java -jar '/var/www/html/jar/MyFile.jar' command"
exec($command, $output, $return);
```

I suspect, that `exec` simple cannot find where `java` is.
How to make it work?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In docker the two containers run completely separate from each other, so when you use `exec` it will try to execute that command within your **php** container as opposed to in the java container. The only way to start a process in the other container is via a HTTP request where in the Java container an API is running which catches this call and executes the correct JAR accordingly.

Another solution could be to use a bigger image for your php container which also includes java so you can execute the jar within your php container.

I hope this answers your question, if anything is unclear please let me know.